# How do I filter on an optional property value only if it exists?

Tags: json, key, jq

I have JSON such as:

`{ "message": "hi" }`

But it can also be of the format:

`{ "message": { "action": "foo" } }`

I want to filter out any records where the message.action == "foo" IF message.action even exists.

If I use the command:

```
jq 'select(.message.action? == null or .message.action? != "foo" )'
```

Then I get zero results. This appears to be because once you check for action, it then filters out any messages that are not objects, but I still want to be able to display `{ message: "hi" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if **message** points to an object which has the key **action** whose value is **foo** instead, and take logical complement of the result. There's no harm in typing a few more letters.

```
select(.message | type == "object" and has("action") and .action == "foo" | not)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also add an explanation of what that all means? The syntax still confuses me

Comment: It literally means: **select** if **message** is of **type** **object** **and** **has** a key named **action** **and** **action**'s value is **foo** without the `| not` part, `not` returns the opposite of its input, like true->false, false->true. These are all written in the manual though

Comment: `and has("action")` can be omitted.

Comment: Correct, just included for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternative operator `//` to provide a default value for `action` when it does not exist (whether because it is missing or because the value is not an object in the first place):

```
jq 'select((.message.action? // "foo") != "foo")'
```

This will accept either `{"message": "hi"}` or `{"message": {"action": "not foo"}}`, but not `{"message": {"action": "foo"}}`.